# How do we run SED with inline file option while it must have twice or more pipe process

Tags: file, sed

How do we do SED as inline file option on many pipe

```
sed -i -E ':k /\b("[^"]+"\s*([A-z]\w*\s*)?)+,?\s*$/{N;s/\s*\n\s*/ /;
            s/\)\s*;/);\n/; bk}' uci.c \
| sed -E 's/\b\s*("[^%"]+")\s*\)\s*;/c\1;/' | sed -E 's/;/;;/'
```

and how to do such in batch files by instructing glob `uci*.c`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are various ways to go about it. If having three separate sed processes is not explicitely needed, you could either combine the three sed scripts into one:

```
sed -i -E \
    ':k /\b("[^"]+"\s*([A-z]\w*\s*)?)+,?\s*$/{N;s/\s*\n\s*/ /;
     s/\)\s*;/);\n/; bk};s/\b\s*("[^%"]+")\s*\)\s*;/c\1;/;s/;/;;/' \
    uci.c
```

or run sed with multiple script arguments:

```
sed -i -E \
    -e ':k /\b("[^"]+"\s*([A-z]\w*\s*)?)+,?\s*$/{N;s/\s*\n\s*/ /;
        s/\)\s*;/);\n/; bk}' \
    -e 's/\b\s*("[^%"]+")\s*\)\s*;/c\1;/' \
    -e 's/;/;;/' \
    uci.c
```

If you want to keep the pipeline, you'll have to use some kind of temp file, either explicitly:

```
tmpf="$(mktemp)"
sed -E ':k /\b("[^"]+"\s*([A-z]\w*\s*)?)+,?\s*$/{N;s/\s*\n\s*/ /;
        s/\)\s*;/);\n/; bk}' uci.c \
| sed -E 's/\b\s*("[^%"]+")\s*\)\s*;/c\1;/' \
| sed -E 's/;/;;/' > "$tmpf"
mv -f "$tmpf" uci.c
```

or implicitly, through a uility like sponge (from [moreutils](https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/)):

```
sed -E ':k /\b("[^"]+"\s*([A-z]\w*\s*)?)+,?\s*$/{N;s/\s*\n\s*/ /;
        s/\)\s*;/);\n/; bk}' uci.c \
| sed -E 's/\b\s*("[^%"]+")\s*\)\s*;/c\1;/' \
| sed -E 's/;/;;/' \
| sponge uci.c
```